# Why my url changes

Tags: php, email

I am making a mail service that redirects the user to the item page, I am making a loop to build the email table, but for some reason my table gets "attacked" and as a result it shows modified like this:

```
<img src="=http://www.mypage.com%2fimage_files%2fOEMDDADHV620W2T_1.jpg" alt="OEMDDADHV620W2T" width="100px" height="10!   0px">
```

which it should be like this

```
<img src="=http://www.mypage.com%2fimage_files%2fOEMDDADHV620W2T_1.jpg" alt="OEMDDADHV620W2T" width="100px" height="100px">
```

also on a button, the item name gets modified like this:

```
<a href="http://www.mypage.com.mx/detail_product.php?art=S%21%20EA-DD4TB-S3" target="_blank" class=""><img style="width:105px;" src="buttonurl"></a>
```

where the art is SEA-DD4TB-S3 not S%21%20EA-DD4TB-S3

This is caused by the webmail or is an issue that can be solved using `urlencode` or `rawurlencode` which I already tried with no success

Comment: Not much evidence to work on it officer :D .. Can we get some more code to know whats going on?

Comment: don't urlencode the entire url it is changing your `/` into encoded characters